# Jenkins: How to create a Job for multiple Java Projects?

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, build

I am using Jenkins to support the build-and deploy process of my microservices. I have managed to create a Jenkins Job that builds a war file and deploys it to a Wildfly Application Server.

But how to create a job which builds and deploys more than one Java project at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [MultiJobPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), create jobs for building and deploying different projects, then unite them in MultiJob and start it.